# Permission Denied on jQuery script with Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

ALl,
I have the following HTML:

```
<a class="display_songs fancybox.ajax" href="display_songs.php">View Current Playlist</a>
```

I then have the following jQuery:

```
$(".display_songs").fancybox({
    'maxWidth'    : 675,
    'maxHeight'   : 800,
    'fitToView'   : true,
    'closeClick'  : false,
    'openEffect'  : 'none',
    'closeEffect' : 'none',
    'scolling'    : 'no',
    'href'        : 'display_songs.php'
});
```

I load Fancybox and jQuery with the following code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-replace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Century_Gothic_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
```

The jQuery that I load is from Google and just copied it into a JS file so I don't go across domains. The error that I get is:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8; AskTbAD2/5.14.1.20007)
Timestamp: Mon, 16 Apr 2012 21:47:14 UTC


Message: Permission denied
Line: 6083
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/wedding/js/jquery.js
```

This works in Firefox, Chrome etc but just not in IE. If I remove the Cufon it also doesn't work. Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: have you tried testing your sample in a server rather than a local host?

Comment: @JFK Yes, my site is hosted and it doesn't work on there. I have other jQuery that works fine on the site but when I try and display the Fancybox is when I get the error.

Comment: well, your error says `http://localhost/wedding/js/jquery.js`. That made me think you were running locally. A link with the issue would be useful

Comment: weirdly I cannot replicate the issue. Check http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/STACK_issueIE_16apr12.html that seems to be working fine even with the cufon error. Of course I don't have a real php file but the rendered html instead. I wonder if there are some php processes inside the display_songs.php file that might be creating the conflict with IE and fancybox.

Comment: BTW, is there any reason to have jQuery, cufon and fancybox inside the `display_songs.php` file?

Comment: @JFK I removed the jQuery, cufon and fancybox from my display_songs.php and it worked good now. Thanks for the suggestion! If you want you can submit that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: permission denied is common error after the wedding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot replicate the issue. Check http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/STACK_issueIE_16apr12.html that seems to be working fine even with the cufon error.

Of course I don't have a real php file but the rendered html instead. I wonder if there are some php processes inside the `display_songs.php` file that might be creating the conflict with IE and fancybox.

Is there any reason to have jQuery, cufon and fancybox inside the `display_songs.php` file? You may not need them.